# Execute scroll event once only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue with trying to add css to the pop-overlay class on scroll after 1500 pixels, but only once. Any help would be appreciated on this.

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(event) {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1500) {
    jQuery('.popbox-overlay').css('display', 'block');
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
  };
  jQuery(this).off(event);
});
```

Comment: Move the `off()` call inside the `if` condition

Comment: unbind the event when meet the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out.

```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(event) {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1500) {
    jQuery('.popbox-overlay').css('display', 'block');
    jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
  };
  jQuery(window).off("scroll")
});
```

Comment: Hi Shaun, I tried it out it works for me if you do not mind to check further please check below base code.
```
jQuery(window).on("scroll", function(event) {
  if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    console.log('run');
  };
  jQuery(window).off("scroll")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the `off()` call into the if conditional.  The modified logic below creates the scroll event listener on the window with a named function.  It also caches the `$(window)` so it is only created once.  Then in the logic, when the overlay is shown, it removes that event listener by performing `off()` with the method.  This way, only that event listener is removed.  You could do simply `off('scroll')` but that would potentially remove more event listeners than you meant to.

I also added a click event listener for the overlay so you can click it to make it hide again, and see that it does not show up again when you scroll to the bottom.

```js
(function($, window, undefined){
  let $popboxOverlay = $('.popbox-overlay').on('click', function(e){
    $popboxOverlay.hide();
  });

  let $window = $(window).on('scroll', function showPopboxOverlay(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > 1500) {
      $popboxOverlay.show();
      $window.scrollTop(0);
      $window.off('scroll', showPopboxOverlay);
    }
  });
}(jQuery, window));
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}

.popbox-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vw;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  
  background-color: rgb(64, 64, 192);
  color: white;
  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Stuff</span>

<div class="popbox-overlay">
  Other Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: That work's thank you. Although the .pop-overlay as a form nested inside it, I will need '.close-btn' to be the event that closes the .pop-overlay div. Do you know what I need to do to make that happen?

Comment: If you have a `.close-btn`, you just have to make a click handler for it, similar to how in my example I made a dummy close by clicking on the overlay.  Instead of doing that close on clicking the overlay, do it upon clicking the close button.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to approach this would be to use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This was designed for use cases like yours: It watches an element and triggers a function when it comes into the viewport (or leaves it). It even supports checking for if an element intersects with another element.

First, you have to set your options for IO and initialize it:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

let targets = document.querySelectorAll('popbox-overlay'); // get each popbox-overlay
targets.forEach(target => { // for each overlay
  observer.observe(target); // we observe it
});
// the callback we setup for the observer will be executed now for the first time
// it waits until we assign a target to our observer (even if the target is currently not visible)
```

Last step is to define what should actually happen once your element comes into view:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   Your popbox-overlay is in the viewport, do something with it
  });
};
```

You can also [unobserve an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) if you only need this to trigger once.

A [polyfill from w3c exists](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers who doesn't support this (IE 11).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javascript to check the first time

```
var firstScrolled = false;

window.onscroll = function(){
        
    if(!firstScrolled)
    {
       // some code
       firstScrolled = true;
    }
};
```